# Convergence in Distribution (Probability Theory) and Weak* Convergence (Functional Analysis)

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I've seen on some online materials that convergence in distribution/law in probability theory corresponds to weak* convergence in functional analysis in some sense.

I guess this has something to do with the Helly's Thm, which states that ''$X_n\to X$ in distribution'' is equivalent to ''$Ef(X_n)\to Ef(X),\forall \text{ bounded continuous function }f$ ''. However, this is not a direct relation at all.

I really want to figure out: In what way can the convergence of random variables in law can be understood as weak* convergence? What is the dual space? Where are the bounded linear functionals? Could someone elaborate on this topic? I've searched and looked into a few materials online, but none of them explains this clearly...

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of thinking about this is that one starts with the space of continuous bounded functions, the measures one is interested in are elements of the dual space, and the convergence of measures is with respect to the weak star topology, according to which all the the maps $\mu \mapsto\langle\mu,f\rangle$ are  continuous.

Of course there are technicalities involved, so this summary is just a road map.